# 再一次地, why is 地 used?

Tags: translation

Here are some sentences for context. To me, leaving out the 地 preserves the meanings:

再一次地感谢大家
让我再一次地想你
微笑,再一次地让我们微笑

Is 再一次地 a set phrase/固定短语?

Here's one w/o the 地:

再一次战胜自己

Comment: Yes, it is completely fine not to use 地. I think 地 merely emphasizes 再一次. If I were to read out the sentence, I would somewhat put stress on 地, which I think it has the effect of emphasizing 再一次 -- it might be my own accent though...

Comment: Are you familiar with the use 地 (de - toneless) in Chinese adverbs? Just wondering. Not sure if this is why you don't understand its usage here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Chinese「地」is the adverb marker. 
It's used bewtween an adverb and the verb it describes.

The phrase「再一次」 acts like a adverb whcih means "do something once again".
So use 「地」after 「再一次」 and the verb behind it。

Example：
「再一次地感谢大家」 --> Thanks everyone once again.

And 「地」can be omitted in this case, so
「再一次地感谢大家」 --> 「再一次感谢大家」
This kind of usage is usually more informal.

The words 「的/地/得」 is quite confusing in Chinese language.
Even Chinese native speakers do not care about the difference between them.

More information please see:
http://eastasiastudent.net/china/mandarin/%E7%9A%84-%E5%9C%B0-%E5%BE%97-summary

Comment: You might want to mention that 地 can be omitted in this case, as explained in the other answers to make this one more complete.

Comment: Usually `地` followed by a verb.

Comment: and now, the primary school of China just teach "的" instead of these 3 chars. aka, others will be retired soon.

Answer (score 2):

再一次地 is not a set phrase. 一 and 地 can often be dropped, and people more often say 再次感谢，再次想你，etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to use 地 but we usually leave it out in conversations. The 地 literally makes the sentence more formal, like in a poem, a speech, or something has strong emotions attached.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

再一次地 并非固定短语。这里只是在语法合乎规范的条件下“凑”成四字短语，使之听起来更大气(rigistre soutenu)。

---

再一次地 is not a set phrase. Here, although 地 is a possibility not essential, we choose to add it to make the phrase into a four-character phrase to sound like a 成语, which sounds more elevated.

Answer (score 1):

地 is just an adverb marker, similar to *-ly* in English.

e.g.

高兴的  happy

高兴地  happily